# In visual studio, when I 'find and replace' in 'entire solution', I get results from 'enc_temp_folder'

Tags: visual-c++

In visual studio (2015), is there a way to prevent getting results from 'enc_temp_folder' when performing a 'find/replace in files'?

This is very irritating since I have to go through twice the number of results and half of them are irrelevant (enc_temp_folder).  Also sometimes I get some of these 'enc_temp_folder' files into my backups too.

I have checked and my 'auto recover' is not even enabled.

Ideally, I would like to disable this 'enc_temp_folder' or at least move it outside of the solution path.

Answer (score 1):

In the Find and Replace window, in the File types filter, you can remove file types and entire folders from the search. For example. here is the one I use : !*\bin*;!*\obj*;!C:\Users*; !*.d;

In your case, if you only want to remove the enc_temp_folder, simply enter a filter like this :
!C:\path_to_your_enc_temp_folder\enc_temp_folder*;

Note that the **!** is a negative filter in this context, thus filtering out the files that match the filter.

You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-in-files?view=vs-2022&source=recommendations#file-types for more information.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).